# Decode netlink message for veth device creation in Linux

Tags: networking, netlink

I want to understand the netlink messages exchanged with the kernel when I run the following commmand to create a pair of veth devices (I am using `Ubuntu 16.04`):

```
$ sudo ip link add veth1 type veth peer name veth2
```

I tried to follow the tutorial at this [link](https://docs.pyroute2.org/debug.html). I used strace and got the following trace related to netlink:

```
$ sudo strace -e trace=network -x -s 16384 -f -o out ip link add veth1 type veth peer name veth2
$ cat out 
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW|SOCK_CLOEXEC, NETLINK_ROUTE) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [32768], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [1048576], 4) = 0
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, 12) = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=6001, groups=00000000}, [12]) = 0
send(3, "\x20\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00", 32, 0) = 32
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"\x34\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x71\x17\x00\x00\xed\xff\xff\xff\x20\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00", 16384}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 52
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 4
sendmsg(3, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"\x5c\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x05\x06\x38\xa2\x16\x5d\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0a\x00\x03\x00\x76\x65\x74\x68\x31\x00\x00\x00\x30\x00\x12\x00\x08\x00\x01\x00\x76\x65\x74\x68\x24\x00\x02\x00\x20\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0a\x00\x03\x00\x76\x65\x74\x68\x32\x00\x00\x00", 92}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 92
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"\x24\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x38\xa2\x16\x5d\x71\x17\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x5c\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x05\x06\x38\xa2\x16\x5d\x00\x00\x00\x00", 32768}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 36
```

For example, I try decoding the messages related to sending.

```
// my test did not have any line breaks
$ echo'\x20\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00' >> message
$ python tests/decoder/decoder.py pyroute2.netlink.rtnl.rtmsg.rtmsg message
20:00:00:00:10:00:05:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
{'attrs': [('RTA_UNSPEC', None)],
 'dst_len': 0,
 'family': 0,
 'flags': 0,
 'header': {'flags': 5,
            'length': 32,
            'pid': 0,
            'sequence_number': 0,
            'type': 16},
 'proto': 0,
 'scope': 0,
 'src_len': 0,
 'table': 0,
 'tos': 0,
 'type': 0}
........................................ 

$ echo '\x5c\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x05\x06\x38\xa2\x16\x5d\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x0a\x00\x03\x00\x76\x65\x74\x68\x31\x00\x00\x00\x30\x00
\x12\x00\x08\x00\x01\x00\x76\x65\x74\x68\x24\x00\x02\x00\x20\x00
\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x0a\x00\x03\x00\x76\x65\x74\x68\x32\x00\x00\x00' >> 
message

 $ python tests/decoder/decoder.py pyroute2.netlink.rtnl.rtmsg.rtmsg message
 5c:00:00:00:10:00:05:06:38:a2:16:5d:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:
 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:0a:00:03:00:76:65:74:68:31:00:00:00:
 30:00:12:00:08:00:01:00:76:65:74:68:24:00:02:00:20:00:01:00:00:00:
 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:0a:00:03:00:76:65:74:68:
 32:00:00:00
 {'attrs': [('RTA_UNSPEC', None),
           ('RTA_IIF', 1752458614),
           ('RTA_VIA', {'addr': 
 '01:00:76:65:74:68:24:00:02:00:20:00:01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:
  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:0a:00:03:00:76:65:74:68:32:00:00:00', 
 'family': 8})],
 'dst_len': 0,
 'family': 0,
 'flags': 0,
 'header': {'flags': 1541,
        'length': 92,
        'pid': 0,
        'sequence_number': 1561764408,
        'type': 16},
 'proto': 0,
 'scope': 0,
 'src_len': 0,
 'table': 0,
 'tos': 0,
 'type': 0}
```

I was expecting the decoding to indicate something about `veth1` or `veth2`, but the decoding does not seem to correlate with veth devices.
I did repeat the decoding in a related [tutorial](https://jvns.ca/blog/2017/09/03/debugging-netlink-requests/) and could get the same result as in the tutorial. I want to ask if the decoding above is correct, and if so, how can it be interpreted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note for readers: in pyroute2 *decoder.py* is available only in [git](https://github.com/svinota/pyroute2/blob/master/tests/decoder/decoder.py).

The correct module should be `ifinfmsg`, which will handle *interface*-related messages (rather than *route*-related messages):

```
$ python tests/decoder/decoder.py pyroute2.netlink.rtnl.ifinfmsg.ifinfmsg message
5c:00:00:00:10:00:05:06:38:a2:16:5d:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:0a:00:03:00:76:65:74:68:31:00:00:00:30:00:12:00:08:00:01:00:76:65:74:68:24:00:02:00:20:00:01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:0a:00:03:00:76:65:74:68:32:00:00:00
{'__align': (),
 'attrs': [('IFLA_IFNAME', 'veth1'),
           ('IFLA_LINKINFO', {'attrs': [('IFLA_INFO_KIND', 'veth'), ('IFLA_INFO_DATA', {'attrs': [('VETH_INFO_PEER', {'index': 0, 'family': 0, '__align': (), 'flags': 0, 'ifi_type': 0, 'change': 0, 'attrs': [('IFLA_IFNAME', 'veth2')]})]})]})],
 'change': 0,
 'family': 0,
 'flags': 0,
 'header': {'flags': 1541,
            'length': 92,
            'pid': 0,
            'sequence_number': 1561764408,
            'type': 16},
 'ifi_type': 0,
 'index': 0}
........................................
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.